# Maintaining data across multiple API requests on node server

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is the problem I am working on.

The client needs to poll the node server for some data using an API. For the node server to respond, it needs a data set (to be read from DB). I want to avoid reading the database in every poll. How do I maintain the data set across multiple polls?

And if this is possible, would it have any impact on server performance.

Answer (score 0):

db query reduction is always a complicated question. my solution is making db query a promise and cache it till it is expired.

For example:

```
var cache = {};
var cachedQuery = function(id) {
  if(id in cache) return cache[id];

  return cache[id] = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    db.query('select * from test where id=?', id, function(err, rows) {
      delete cache[id];
      if(err) reject(err);
      else resolve(rows);
    }
  });
}
```

Assume that you have 100+ queries at the same time that shares the same request id, those queries will share the same db request. The request is established when the first query comes, and all queries will return the same result when the query completes.

For a more generic usage, you can use a lru-cache to store the promises created, giving it a expriation time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an in-memory cache. The idea is that before making a trip to the database, you check if the requested value exists in the cache. If it is - serve it. If not - fetch from database, save to cache and return it.

Serving from memory is the fastest you can get. There are existing solutions for node out there, like [node-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache).